# How to handle Georgian language column when exporting data to csv file?

Tags: r, character-encoding

I have dataframe in R, but one column contains Georgian character. I want to export  it in csv file, I am using the folloing comman :`write.csv(data,"data.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")`.I tried several encoding options, but none of them works.
What is the solution, to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: As an armenian, I advise you to use the function stringi::stri_encode(string, from, to="UTF-8) in your data.frame before exporting it which worked for me

You can find the good "from" argument by trying to import manually a data.frame with georgian characters

Comment: When I am opening this file in r data frame, Georgian language looks fine, but when I export this file, it has unknown simbols.

Comment: Hi Mariam. This problem is often dependent on your operating system's encoding. It should be easier to export from a *nix SO, like Linux or osX/Mac. If you are opening it in Windows, say in Excel, make sure you import it as a UTF-8.

Comment: I am importing data from the SQL server and I am working on windows.